# How to append multiple .txt files to one file without header line

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, script

I have 100,000 .txt files with format below:

```
bygrp,colnum,beta
100005,1,0.629519434191718
100005,2,-0.500000000026516
100005,3,0.560850895321124
100005,4,0.119624318119292
100005,5,0.257676682753309
```

And the filenames are Job19_beta1.txt,...,job19_beta100000.txt

I have created total.txt that includes only the header line: bygrp,colnum, beta.

I want to append only the 3rd row (colnum=2 in the table) from the 100,000 files to total.txt, without header.

How can I write a script to do it? I think I need to write for... do... loop and then copy, but cannot figure it out...

I'm actually a SAS analyst but have got a project which is required to use command prompt to upload data. I've googled a lot of codes but still am struggling about the script. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like [this question][1] is pretty similar. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939327/merge-many-txt-file-contents-and-skip-first-line-in-batch-command-file

Comment: @Xupicor write an answer then :)

Comment: @Davidenko I did - bit it was trivial and thus was automatically converted into comment. :P That's good too, because I wanted to comment - but didn't have the privilege yet. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Testing on bash in linux (can't guarantee for windows), this looks promising:

```
for i in (*.txt)
do
tail -n +2 "$i" >> total.txt
done
```

The `-n +2` for `tail` outputs the 2nd line onward, skipping only the first line.

Or reading from your file list in a.txt (probably superfluous use of cat, and if there aren't any newlines in the filenames):

```
for i in $(cat a.txt)
do
tail -n +2 "$i" >> total.txt
done
```

Or using `find` should work too, probably easier if the 100,000 text files are all in the same folder tree & you need to do some digging.

```
find folder/ -name "*.txt" -exec tail -n +2 '{}' >> total.txt  \;
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the filenames from a file:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    sed 1d "$filename"
done < a.txt >> total.txt
```

More efficient, in that you don't have to invoke sed for every file:

```
xargs awk 'FNR != 1' < a.txt >> total.txt
```

That will accumulate as many file arguments to awk as a the command can hold.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to append all the data from the 100,000 files to total.txt but without header since it already exists in total.txt

In that case, and using bash and unix-style tools:

```
tail -qn +2 job19_beta{1..100000}.txt >>total.txt
```

#### How it works

- `job19_beta{1..100000}.txt` expands to the list of files that you want **in their correct order**.
- `tail -qn +2 job19_beta{1..100000}.txt`

  This writes to stdout the contents of all files starting with line 2.

  `-n +2` tells `tail` to start with line 2.  `-q` tells `tail` to be quiet and not print headers when changing files.
- `>>total.txt`

  This cause the output of the tail command to be appended to `total.txt`.

#### Alternative using `a.txt`

If you want to read the file names in from `a.txt`, then:

```
while IFS= read -r fname; do tail -n +2 "$fname"; done <a.txt >>total.txt
```

You didn't mention how the file names are separated in `a.txt` so I assumed that they are one per line.  (Note that it is possible for file names to contain newlines in their names so this is not a general solution.)